# Setup Local Homepage

Tags: php, macos, apache, webserver, localhost

http://mallinson.ca/post/osx-web-development/

I've been trying to get this working -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724583/localhost-works-dev-results-in-403 (still not working, but after getting it working, I have this question as well)

Once I get it working (after someone explains), how should I go about setting up the local homepage? Where do I put the files provided?

How does the www system work? Each time I want a new site, do I just add another folder under /sites directory? Do I put everything for the site in /wwwroot or is that only root and i create a new folder per directory (/about, /contact, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment, but don't have enough reputation points. I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but have a look here, maybe it will answer your question:

http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp